How do I delete a vertex from a path in Google Earth
I am trying to delete vertices from a path in a Google Earth project that I created on the web version, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do it.
I've tried to do this on the web and iPad versions, and have found that in edit mode, right-clicking points does nothing; while the desktop app doesn't even seem to be able to access projects saved on my Google Drive. Is there any way to do this?
